# Retrieve image from folder in my computer using php

Tags: php, server

I'm trying to retrieve image from server using the following code, but it isn't working:

```
<?php
    $result=file_get_contents("http://192.168.43.89/phpmyadmin/uploads/8.jpg");   
    header("content-type:image/jpeg");
    echo '<img src="' .base64_decode($result). '">';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You firstly need to encode the image data you fetch to base64 using `base64_encode()`, then you must include the data properly inside your `src`-attribute (syntax: `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>`), like this:

```
<?php
    $result=base64_encode(file_get_contents("http://192.168.43.89/phpmyadmin/uploads/8.jpg"));   
    //header("content-type:image/jpeg"); --> you don't need this if you are outputting HTML, only if you are outputting the image directly
    echo "<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,$result\">";
?>
```

source: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/